# Terraform stuck at still creating step and timeouts while creating Azure Service Bus Queue

Tags: networking, terraform, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-rm

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFWXY.jpg)

Terraform apply is successful creating the Azure Service Bus Queue but, not updating it in the terraform state. It gets stuck at in still creating step and timeout after 30 minutes as per the default timeout policy.

I tried running the plan using the old terraform and azurerm version but the issue is still the same.

This issue isn't there while creating Azure Service Bus Topics within the same Azure Service Bus Namespace.

Comment: Are you trying to deploy the sample template [`azurerm_servicebus_queue`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/servicebus_queue) from terraform registry. @Saurav Garg

Comment: I have my custom code written which is only creating queue and utilizing the data block to get the namespace id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Timeout issue for me was with argument named `lock_duration`. For which the value passed was `P0DT0H5M0S` but it is expecting for short formatted string like `PT5M`.

Don't know why this was happening as it is ISO 8601 timespan duration format.

Answer (score 0):

> Terraform stuck at still creating step and timeouts while creating Azure Service Bus Queue:- -

In the latest Azure RM provider versions, there is a property called [timeouts](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/servicebus_queue#timeouts) to apply for any resource like service bus queue. If you've already applied the `timeout` field, consider increasing the timeout to `60m` or more as shown.

```bash
resource "azurerm_servicebus_queue" "main" {
  timeouts {
    create = "80m"
    update = "xxx"
    delete = "xx"
  }
}
```

*Note:* Verify the terraform configuration of your `.tf` file's `azurerm_servicebus_queue` by comparing it to the template structure from the terraform registry once.

*After checking all the above, I tried deploying a service bus queue in my environment and was able to perform it successfully as shown.*

```bash
provider "azurerm"{
features{}
}
data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "caroline"
}

resource "azurerm_servicebus_namespace" "example" {
  name                = "jahservicebus-namespace"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  sku                 = "Standard"
}

resource "azurerm_servicebus_queue" "example" {
  name         = "tfex_servicebus_queue"
  namespace_id = azurerm_servicebus_namespace.example.id

  enable_partitioning = true
   timeouts {
    create = "80m"
    update = "xxx"
    delete = "xx"
  }
}
```

*Deployment succeeded:*

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

This can also happen if terraform requires an upgrade. Before deploying the resource, run `terraform init -upgrade`.

If the issue persists, delete the cache in `AzCLI` using [`az cache purge`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/cache?view=azure-cli-latest) and relaunch the resource. To avoid conflicts, use the
`rm terraform.tfstate` command to remove the current state file.

Comment: I tried increasing timeout to 60min. But it still gives same error after 60mins. 
Used terraform init -upgrade and az cache purge before init.
The terraform apply is being ran from Azure DevOps pipeline